# C#, Windows Forms: Cant start center the form

Tags: c#, winforms, centering

```
  static void Main()
    {
          Application.EnableVisualStyles();
          Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
          Application.Run(new MainScreen());
    }
```

This is my main that creates and runs the main screen, I have tried using:

- Form.StartPosition = CenterScreen/ CenterParent
- Manually changing the form location in the constructor.
- I have even tried creating the form separately then changing its StartPosition and later calling it in the Application.Run().

Non of these have worked, it just keeps showing on the left top corner of the screen.
Any ideas on how to center the form?

Comment: Use `Form.CenterToScreen` method

Comment: @AmeyaDeshpande the CenterToScreen method _" is not intended to be used directly from your code."_

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have somewhere a line of code that sets the StartPosition to Manual? and your Location property is 0,0?

Comment: @Steve after looking in the form properties Ive noticed that windowState was set to maximized which probably caused it. it is now fixed thanks everyone for their answers.

Comment: I suggest to post an answer with your findings. While this is a simple error, it could be useful for future readers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried this . a work around

```
this.Location = new Point((Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width - this.Width) / 2,
                          (Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height - this.Height) / 2);
```

Comment: Ill mark this as an answer, I have put it in the constructor and that worked after noticing that the WindowState property was set to Maximized which caused the problem. changed it to normal and it works now, thanks.

Comment: I would also recommend using `Screen.FromControl(this)` instead of `Screen.PrimaryScreen`.